# Count ID group by month

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I have 2 tables :

Table payment

```
id | customer | date | offer | type | init
```

Table evo_offer

```
id | offer
```

The tables `payment` and `evo_offer` are related by `payment.offer` and `evo_offer.offer`.

What I'd like to do is retrieve the total of payments with `type = 'RENEWAL' AND init != 1` and where their related offer has the field `assistance_administrative` set to 1.

So I did the following query :

```
SELECT COUNT(p.id), DATE_FORMAT(p.date, '%Y-%m') AS month
FROM payment p
INNER JOIN evo_offer o ON p.offer = o.offer
WHERE p.type = "RENEWAL"
AND p.init != 1
AND o.assistance_administrative = 1
GROUP BY month
```

But the data I get are totally impossible. Anything wrong in my query?

Comment: Unless you show an example of the data you have, the results you get and why they are impossible it's very hard to tell where your error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was the use of "month" in my date_format alias. Month is a keyword, and cant be used as alias apparently

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be the AND p.init != 1

try to write it as AND p.init <> 1